# preposition + the

Tags: grammar, expressions

should “the” be omitted when it is used along with the prepositions: in, on, across, etc.? Like in the following sentences, and I'm speaking generally:

1) some birds live in ***mountains\the mountains***

2) some plants live deep in ***water\the water***

3) birds fly over ***plains\the plains***

Comment: It can be removed, but not *should be omitted*.

Comment: thanks, mama, you mean that it sounds more common to keep it; like when I say "birds fly over the plains". Do you get the general idea of birds flying over nature plains? So it's not necessary to omit "the".

Comment: Using an article or not has **nothing** to do with prepositions. Any article or no article can occur after any preposition, depending on the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The absence of the article, the so-called "zero-article", can be used to refer to the noun in general as mode or manner:

> Some plants grow *on land* while others are aquatic and grow *in water*.

The article "the" can cast the noun it specifies as something everyone knows about, something ubiquitous, not as a particular instance:

> We must not speak loudly in *the library*.
>
> In *the city*, children often play in *the street*.
>
> Some plants grow on *the land* and others in *the water*.

And the plural can refer to the noun generally:

> *Airplanes* have *monitors* that warn *pilots* to pull up when flying too low over *mountains*.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I think I get it now. Please correct me if I'm wrong; Some hawks live high in the mountain, and those hawks fly over plains to hunt mice. also, they can fly over rivers to feed on fish that live in the river.

Comment: Your sentence is quite good. But I would suggest one change. When speaking of mountains that begin as lower foothills and then rise to greater heights the further into them you go, we would say *high in the mountains*.  Plural, "mountains".  The meaning is: farther into the mountain range where the mountains rise to greater heights. And when we wish to refer to a specific location on a single mountain, we would use singular "mountain" and "on": *The hut was situated high on the mountain.*

Comment: ok, good I'll use " high in the mountains ", bear with me, please. is there any thing thing wrong by saying; there are a lot of fish species that live in the river\ that live in rivers. (generally speaking)

Comment: In that particular example, **species that live in rivers** (plural without article) is the better choice, since **species that live in *the* river** doesn't have the meaning "river species". It is not always possible to give an absolute rule that works in every instance. While  *In the city, children often play in the street* is an idiomatic generalization about urban life, and does not refer to any particular city or any particular street, *Many fish live in the river* is not an idiomatic generalization about river species, at least not without further context, since river is not ubiquitous

Comment: ... or universal.  But we could say *In the jungle, many species live in the canopy* since all jungles have a tree canopy.  But we can't say *In the jungle, many species live in the river* since not all jungles have a river.  The statement would be idiomatic if it were referring to a particular jungle with a river.

Comment: To further complicate matters, the domain against which the universality test is made can be arbitrarily limited in scope. *In the desert, we often ride the camel*. Not all deserts have camels, but there  "the desert" is understood to refer to the desert(s) the speaker is familiar with.